# Are there any published adventures located in Geb

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, campaign-settings

My party wants to travel to Geb and now I am looking for adventures located there to get a feeling for the atmosphere. I have checked the big Adventure Paths so far but could not find any. I know of lots of PFS Adventures but since I do not know how to search all of them I would like to ask here if anyone knows such an adventure.

What official Paizo and Pathfinder Society adventures and adventure paths are set in Geb?

Comment: @doppelspooker Seems to me that the question is asking “Are there any?” not “Recommend one for me.” The former *could* be over-broad (though the research in the question suggests it is not), but it’s not the same as recommendation.

Comment: @KRyan That works for me. Reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one published adventure, on a scenario for Pathfinder Society, [You Only Die Twice](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventureFinder/byRegion/geb), where

> you are turned into a real zombie before going there.

[Mythic Realms](http://paizo.com/products/btpy90q7?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Mythic-Realms) has information on [Mechitar](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Mechitar), the capital of Geb, and describes a little more about [Arazni](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Arazni). [Undead Unleashed](http://paizo.com/products/btpy991t?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Undead-Unleashed) contains information about [Seldeg Bhedlis](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Seldeg_Bhedlis), a *citizen* of Geb, and his lair **Fort Halg**, which could become a short adventure.

When looking for adventures, you can use Paizo's [Adventure Finder](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventureFinder) and filter [by region](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventureFinder/byRegion).